# Flutter: add date and time from two different variables to convert to UTC

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to merge these two date and time variables and have another variable called `var toUTC`.

I have two variables for date and time from the `Date Picker` and `Time Picker`.

```
var selectedDate;
var selectedTime;

print(selectedDate); // 2021-02-06 00:00:00.000
print(selectedTime); // 1:15:00.000000
```

The `var selectedDate` has the time but I don't want to use this. I want to replace it with the value from `var selectedTime`.

What I am trying to do is

```
print(toUTC) // 2021-02-06 1:15:00.00000 <---- merge selectedDate and selectedTime
```

to convert to `UTC` time.

I've tried to take only `2021-02-06` and merge with `selectedTime`, but I failed to convert to `UTC`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```dart
final toUTC = DateTime(selectedDate.year, selectedDate.month, selectedDate.year, 
selectedTime.hour, selectedTime.minute);
```

Or if its something you are going to need to do regularly you could make an extension for it. The below does it by passing the hour and minute in as separate variables, but you could change that to be another DateTime value if you would prefer.

```dart
extension DateTimeExtensions on DateTime {

 /// Creates a new date time with the given date but with the time
 /// specified from [time]
 DateTime withTime([int hour = 0, int minute = 0]) =>
     DateTime(this.year, this.month, this.day, hour, minute);

}
```

To convert to UTC there is the method toUtc() on the DateTime class. I'm not sure if you've just not spotted that or if there is an issue I'm not seeing?

Comment: I was trying to use `.toUtc()`. But, was struggling to put two values together! cheers

Answer (score 0):

///maps[0]['TimeInTime'] = 12:25:55

var arr = maps[0]['TimeInTime']!.split(':');

var  TodayFrom = DateTime(DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month, DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 1)).day, int.parse(arr[0]), int.parse(arr[1]),00,00);

Answer (score 0):

To build on [JayDev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65585688/9787021), you could also create an extension method that directly accepts a TimeOfDay.

```
extension DateTimeExtension on DateTime {
  DateTime at(TimeOfDay time) {
    return copyWith(hour: time.hour, minute: time.minute);
  }
}
```

And use it like so:

```
final selectedDateTime = selectedDate.at(selectedTime);
```